# Return multiple values in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-controller

I'm just new in laravel. I want to know. how to return multiple data/value.

```
public function readItems() {
    $data1 = Data1::all ();
    $data = Data::all ();

    return $data;
}
```

I'm quite confuse how to do it. I don't to return it as a view, i just want to return only the data. i hope someone could help. thanks a lot..

Comment: Do you mean to return them as JSON in an API?

Comment: I'm not using as an api. its just like an ajax. Right now. it pass correctly but my page only views the datas of the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could return an array like :

```
return [data1, $data];
```

In the other side read it like :

```
$response = readItems();

$data1 = $response[0];
$data  = $response[1];
```

Comment: I'm having issue to display it on my pages. It only view the object by json string

Comment: Do you have always the problem bro ?

Comment: My object json string doens't load. i make a few changes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51842364/4555497 this link. this is my issue..

Comment: pls take a look and see whats the problem.

Comment: I'm checking, could you give me the link of the tutorial you're following?

Comment: No I mean the one you're talking about here _i'm a newbie that still follow some tutorials_

Answer (score 1):

You can send data to view as like below :

```
return view('index', ['Data_One'=>$data, 'Data_Two'=>$data1]);
```

Comment: _I don't to return it as a view, i just want to return only the data_

Answer (score 0):

you can return value like this

```
[
            'couponName' => $coupon->couponName,
            'couponCode' => $coupon->couponCode,
            'qty' => $coupon->qty,
            'startDate' => $coupon->startDate,
            'endDate' => $coupon->entDate,
            'userId' => $coupon->userId,
]
```