# Display in v-for laravel-vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-5.6

EDITED:

I'm using Vue.js and I'm having an issue that my object JSON-string doesn't show.

> The problem is the object string doesn't display in v-for.

**JS**

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#ob-rapper',

    data:{
        items:[],
    },
    mounted: function mounted(){
        this.getVueItems();
    },
    methods:{
        getVueItems: function getVueItems() {
          var _this = this;
          axios.get('/viewrequestsample').then(function (response) {
            _this.items = response.data;
          });
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public function viewRequestSample(){
    $data = OBMaster::all();
    return $data;
}
```

**route:**

```
Route::get ( '/requestsample', function () {
    return view ( 'Approvers.RequestSample' );
} );
Route::get('/viewrequestsample', 'AdminPagesController@viewRequestSample');
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="card">
  <div id="ob-rapper">
    <div class="card-body">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable responsive dataTable" id="DataTables_Table_0" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">
        <thead>
          <tr role="row">
            <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Date registered: activate to sort column ascending" >
              Name of Employee
            </th>
            <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Role: activate to sort column ascending" >
              Date Filed
            </th>
            <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Status: activate to sort column ascending">
              Status
            </th>
            <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Actions: activate to sort column ascending">
              Actions
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <p class="text-center alert alert-success">Deleted Successfully!</p>

        <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
           <tr v-for="item in items">
              <td>@{{ item.id }}</td>
              <td>@{{ item.emp_id }}</td>
              <td>@{{ item.date_filed }}</td>
              <td>@{{ item.obdate}}</td>
              <td>@{{ item.obfrom}}</td>
              <td>@{{ item.obto}}</td>
              <td>@{{ item.created_a}}</td>
              <td>@{{ item.updated_at}}</td>
              <td id="show-modal" class="btn btn-info" ><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
              <td id="show-modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
           </tr>            
        </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

..............................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Are you using the datatable plugin?

Comment: yes. its set to   $masterIds = OBMaster::all(); return $masterIds;

Comment: @ChinLeung bdw. i change it the axios route to /viewrequestsample and also the controller.

Comment: @gil Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function and CSRF token not found:

Comment: Are `items` in your Vue Dev Tools undefined? You could omit the other 2nd mounted word in `mounted: function mounted()` just `mounted: function()` is fine.

Comment: @gil .like this ?   mounted: function(){
        this.getVueItems();
    },

Comment: Yes. Is the HTML your showing is inside a Vue component not blade.php? If yes, `{{ csrf_field }}` code will not work and must be remove from there.

Comment: @gil .i've already remove. but still the same

Comment: Your problem isn't clear enough you need to limit your code to the important parts and also the errors generated.

Comment: @gil .there's an error it says; jQuery.Deferred exception: url.indexOf is not a function TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function .Since i use a lot of jquery that might distract the vue.js function?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` must be a function that returns your data.

Like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        items:[]
    }
}
```

Question: Is your interpolation tag defined to @{{}} correctly?

Comment: to be honest not. I don't know if i did correctly. i just follow a tutorial and do a little experiment.

Comment: its the same in the tutorial.     <tr v-for="item in items">
                            <td>@{{ item.id }}</td>
                            <td>@{{ item.name }}</td>
                            <td>@{{ item.age }}</td>
                            <td>@{{ item.profession }}</td>

Comment: yes. that correct. i fillow whats in the table from my database

Comment: Still nothing sir. if i open that localhost:8000/viewrequestsample/ .it does view the object string. but when in the  localhost:8000/viewrequestsample/ it doesn't put any in the v-for.

Comment: .sir. ur sample works properly. but mine isn't. Is there something a problem with my routes or controller?.

Comment: What exactly your browser render?

Comment: .the only error it make is this jQuery.Deferred exception: url.indexOf is not a function TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function. Im using google chrome